# strlen() compile time optimization

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11

Few days ago I discovered that you can find compile-time `strlen` using something like this:

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr size_t strlen_(const char (&data)[N]) noexcept{
    return N - 1;
}
```

If it's compiled, then all is good. You can add overload such this:

```
size_t strlen_(const char *s) noexcept{
    return strlen(s);
}
```

Then it will always compiles.

My question is - does C++ `<cstring>` uses something like this and if it does not - why?

Comment: If I use `char x[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};`, that'd produce an unexpected result...

Comment: @KerrekSB, that's not C-style string.

Comment: `char x[10] = "abc";` is a c-string though, and that will produce an unexpected result.

Comment: It does not. There is no compile-time optimizations - it takes up to much space.

Comment: "If I make my code more complex and obscure, maybe the compiler will optimize it better" -- doubt it.

Comment: well. in specific cases my code works for sure. there must be no doubt about it. question is does it really pay off.

Comment: http://ideone.com/IfKUHV and http://ideone.com/eNokov

Comment: `cout << strlen_("hello\0world") << " != " << strlen("hello\0world") << '\n';` Produces: `11 != 5`

Comment: I know. this is abuse of the API and you do not suppose to use it this way. I works with compile time strings you know.

Answer (score 9):

No, it doesn't. Because it gives the wrong answer.

```
char x[10] = "abc";
int correct_length   = std::strlen(x);  // 3
int incorrect_length = strlen_(x);      // 9
```

Also, with your 2 overloads, the template will never be called. The non-template one accepting a `const char*` will always be preferred.

This doesn't mean that strlen can't be calculated at compile time with some compiler magic. But it can't be done this way, using the language proper.

Comment: `char x[10] = "abc";` is not constant string

Comment: @Calvin: What's your point? `strlen` needs to work on both constant and non-constant strings, and the result wouldn't be different even if I made it constant.

Comment: I think the point is that the non-const string would not match the const arg in the template -- so only something like `strlen_("abc")` would match and it give the right result

Comment: @Soren: Wrong on both accounts.

Comment: We can only do compile time optimization on constant literal string which length is known at compile time. Passing non const char array implies the content might change out of eye of the compiler, which should fall back to traditional `strlen()` and is not what OP concern of.

Comment: @Calvin: You can't overload based on whether something is a compile time constant. Even if there weren't other problems with this approach (mentioned in my post), the function cannot know that what it has is a string literal, or even that it is actually const, because you can make a const reference to a non-const thing.

Comment: I'm not saying that was good approach, indeed you see I'm against it as my answer, the code is buggy, even you could fix the code it is just  an unnecessary hack for something compiler also could do. But then I assume the OP cares on compile time optimization for `strlen()`, which we focus on literal string only.

Comment: @Calvin does not matter, it has issue with literal as well: `"abc\0 cde"`

Comment: "abc\0cde" is different and I agree it is an accepted bug for the topic.

Comment: @Calvin: *"which we focus on literal string only"* -- We *can't* focus on string literals only. There is no way to detect that what you have is a string literal.

Answer (score 5):

Your `strlen_`returns the size of array`data`, not the size of a null-terminated string. A correct implementation would be:

```
constexpr size_t ct_strlen( const char* s ) noexcept
{
  return *s ? 1 + ct_strlen(s + 1) : 0;
}
```

Comment: 1 up. I deliberately did not said anything about this solution. However this will slow down a lot if it is executed at runtime. C++17 allows "normal" for loop, so then it will be a solution I think.

Comment: @Nick will it? I see a tail-recursion optimisation opportunity here that would make it equivalent in performance to actual `strlen`. Admittedly it would take some code rearranging and I don't know whether a compiler would do that.

Comment: I have forgotten that C tail recursion is optimized for years. I will try that.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is buggy.

The correct way to do compile time optimization on `strlen()` is, surprisingly, just call `strlen()`. modern compile like clang will optimize away unnecessary `strlen()` when it knows the length at compile time.

Also, in most case `sizeof` comes in handy when you, the programmer, use it properly with variable holding literal strings. like:

```
const char foo[] = "Hello World";
size_t len = sizeof(foo)-1; // 11
```

Note that this has some assumption and if you do this you make yourself trouble but not make your life simple:

```
const char foo[] = "Hello World\01234";
size_t len = sizeof(foo)-1; // 16
```

---

EDITED: To make the obvious more looks like an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `strlen`_ does not work: http://ideone.com/PNNeaX

Also: I know for a fact that visual studio 2015 optimizes all kinds of `strlen` calls, even in situations where I had my doubts, which were gone when I checked the assembly output, which did not generate `runtime` `strlen` calls.

And as @Calvin says, Clang seems to do the same. So there's really no reason for that.

Comment: Don't understand how that answers the question?

Comment: actually it does answer the question

Answer (score 2):

Followup from ZDF answer.

I did test and it seems like premature optimization.

## Code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

constexpr unsigned MAX = 1000 * 1000 * 250;


constexpr size_t strlen_c(const char* s) noexcept{
    return *s ? 1 + strlen_c(s + 1) : 0;
}


int main(){
    constexpr const char *s = "Hi, my name is Malcolm and I am very good boy...";

    unsigned sum = 0;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < MAX; ++i){
        sum += strlen(s) + i;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

## Results:

Code was compiled with:

```
gcc   x.cc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic
gcc   x.cc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic -O3
clang x.cc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic
clang x.cc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic -O3
```

and here is how much time it took:

```
------------------------------------
|         | GCC       | CLANG      |
------------------------------------
| len     | 0m1.506s  | 0m0.743s   |
| len O3  | 0m0.001s  | 0m0.002s   |
| lenc    | 1m5.476s  | 0m56.871s  |
| lenc O3 | 0m12.267s | 0m0.060s   |
------------------------------------
```

Clang appears to be bit faster, but with full optimization, `constexpr strlen_c()` did not pay off.

Let me know if I did something wrong in the code.

Comment: clang and gcc, at least, are able to detect if the string is declared as a constant expression (it looks like this is optional, not standard) and it replaces the call to `strlen` with the string's length. Therefore, it does not make sense to worry about speed optimization. See [here](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) the assembly output.